# Term for machinery of polish sanding grinding

Tags: meaning, terminology, category

Is there any English term which refer to general category of machines which perform polish, sanding, grinding and finishing of mechanical(especially metals)?

Comment: What you're referring to is generally a series of steps that remove progressively finer amounts of material.  Grinding, then sanding, then finishing (applying a protective coating), then polishing.  They involve different equipment.  Grinding and sanding are preparation steps, finishing and polishing are often called just finishing.  To the extent there is a single term or type of equipment, that varies by industry.  For example, in the automotive repair  industry, that would make up a major part of "body work", so the equipment would collectively be referred to in that way.  (cont'd)

Comment: A lot would depend on the nature of what was being worked on and what steps were involved.  For example, in manufacturing heavy equipment, all of those steps, and the related equipment, might be referred to as "finishing".  I'm not sure there is a universal word that encompasses that machinery.  Ash's suggestion of "metalworking" would cover pretty much any/all equipment used in any facet of working with metal, not just the steps you list here.  Can you provide some more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen advertisements in the past for **Metalworking machinery**.

Comment: Despite all answers are great, this one refers to a more general term which I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

That could be called **surface finishing** tools or equipment.

At [this link](http://www.csunitec.com/metal-surface-finishing?utm_campaign=surface%20finishing%20machines&keyword=metal%20surface%20finish%20equipment), the vendor calls equipment the does all of these things *surface finishing* tools.

[This business](http://www.keytronic.com/home/capabilities/precision-metal-stamping-fabricating-and-finishing) differentiates types of finishing and calls this process **mechanical finishing** as opposed to other finishing.

> Mechanical Finishing: De-burring, Tumbling, Grinding, Sanding and Texturing, Polishing
>
> Other Finishing: Painting, Powder Coating, Paint, Pad Coating, Silk Screening, Mechanical Assembly, Inspection, Packaging and Labeling

Answer (score 1):

Usually the machines for each step have their own obvious names:

- *Grinder* for grinding
- *Sander* for sanding
- *Polisher* for polishing or lapping (also *lapping machine* for the latter)

These are all examples of [*abrasive machining*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrasive_machining) processes, so the term *abrasive machine*, while not standard, would be easily understood in an appropriate context.